# Phantomjs works but is very slow

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, webpage-screenshot

I am trying to take a screenshot of a webpage with PhantomJS. Specifically, I am using the example of capturing `espn.com` from [this](http://skookum.com/blog/dynamic-screenshots-on-the-server-with-phantomjs/) example. My code looks like this:

```
var page = new WebPage(); 
    page.open('http://www.espn.com', function (status) {
    page.render('fb.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

I then go to my PhantomJS directory with either my terminal or command prompt and run:

```
phantomjs shotty.js
```

Everything runs great, however it takes 6-8 seconds to complete the output image. Is that normal? Is there a faster way to accomplish this so that it completes in a second or less?

I am using CentOS and Windows 7. Both boxes have 8GB of RAM, 3.2 GHz CPU, and I'm getting 22Mbp/s down and 1Mbp/s up on speedtest.net

Comment: It took about 7 seconds to render the page in my desktop browser; so yes, that seems normal.

Comment: Thank you for verifying!

Comment: DISABLE IPV6 and in Internet explorer "Click internet Options" =>  Click Connections => Click Lan Settings =>UNCHECK “Automatically detect settings

Comment: Taking the screenshot is fast, but to start the actual process is very slow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes this is normal. When you attempt to render, PhantonJS will still wait for the `page.open` event to fire the `load` event to signify that the entire DOM has been loaded.

Take a look at what happens when I load `espn.com` locally on my system. 
It takes ~2 seconds for DOMContentLoaded to finish, and then ~7 seconds for the `ready` event to fire.

[image]

Comment: The operation itself should be fast, depending on the page. The slow thing is the process creation of phantomjs.exe!

Answer (score 25):

Well, in my case, the page was waiting for some GET requests and was not able to reach the requests' server and it kept waiting for long. I could only figure it out when i used the remote debugger option.

```
phantomjs --remote-debugger-port=9000 loadspeed.js <some_url>
```

and inside the `loadspeed.js` file add this below code:

```
page.onResourceRequested = function (req) {
    console.log('requested: ' + JSON.stringify(req, undefined, 4));
};

page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {
    console.log('received: ' + JSON.stringify(res, undefined, 4));
};
```

and then loading localhost:9000 in any webkit browser (safari/chrome) and seeing the console logs where i could figure out it was waiting for some unreachable requests for a long time.

TO BYPASS THIS - REDUCE THE TIMEOUT by adding below to the same `loadspeed.js` file:

```
page.settings.resourceTimeout = 3000; //in milliseconds
```

and things were very quick after that. Hope this helps

Comment: +1 and I wanted to add that by controlling timeout you can skip waiting for the whole page to load and work with a partial page.

Comment: This was a big help. +1

Comment: This is not a complete and working example and therefor not that helpful.

Comment: This was extremely helpful.  Thank you.  @Myz, here's a complete working example: 
var page = require('webpage').create(),
 address = 'your url';
page.settings.resourceTimeout = 3000;
page.open(menuURL, function(status) { 
    if (status === 'success') {
        /*success code here*/
    }
}

Comment: How do I use the remote debugger? It shows me a link named loadspeed.js, then when I click into it, a F12-like page is appeared but no any data in it.

Comment: It doesn't help, if I use `page.evaluate` to check for the existence of an element, it takes 10 sec to complete, in chrome less than a 6 sec with `cache disabled`.

Comment: I checked it again, the request completes very fast in my case, but it takes up to 7s for the phantomjs.exe process to be created, that is what is slow here. I am not sure, if it is possible to create the process once and reuse it for further requests...perhaps someone knows.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't thought that the following would work but for me it did (on Windows):

open Internet Explorer > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings and disable the "Automatically detect settings"

original Post: https://plus.google.com/+MatthiasG%C3%B6tzke/posts/9v9BMCJj2k6